# Magento2 detect database deadlock event

Tags: database, magento2.3.2, deadlock

I want to detect database deadlock event in my Magento2 (2.3.2) store. Based on that I want to send email to higher authority persons to let them know about deadlock instantly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of googling, I found below extension which I also modified little bit according to my project requirements:

> https://www.cadence-labs.com/2018/09/magento-2-deadlock-retry-module/

Anyone can use it to detect database deadlock events on their projects. If you have queries related to this you may ask me in comment section.

Thanks,

Comment: Just be aware that if you've got a deadlock by continually retrying you could end up with more deadlocks. But if it's just detection maybe you should put it up on github

Comment: Hello @DominicXigen, Yes this was actually deadlock retry module which I used as deadlock detection by modifying some module code as per my requirements.

Comment: @PratikNavapara, I have same requirement as yours. I want to send email during deadlock occurs (only if order payment get deducted and order is not placed on Magento). I am facing this issue on 2.4.6

Comment: @ArunSharma Yes I was facing the same issue like the payment happened successfully but order could not be created in Magento admin. So I have used this extension as a reference and customised it further to satisfy my custom requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to integrate Sentry with [this extension](https://github.com/justbetter/magento2-sentry) and then [create an alert](https://docs.sentry.io/product/alerts/create-alerts/) that matches errors that contain "deadlock" (or even "sql").